# Pandas: Duplicated groupby response

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I found a very strange behaviour with the current Panadas' groupby method. Let's take the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Branch' : 'A A A A A B'.split(),
'Buyer': 'Carl Mark Carl Joe Joe Carl'.split(),
'Quantity': [1,3,5,8,9,3],
'Date' : [
    DT.datetime(2013,1,1,13,0),
    DT.datetime(2013,1,1,13,5),
    DT.datetime(2013,10,1,20,0),
    DT.datetime(2013,10,2,10,0),
    DT.datetime(2013,12,2,12,0),                                      
    DT.datetime(2013,12,2,14,0),
    ]})
```

If I want to group now by Week and Branch using:

```
gr = df.groupby([df.Date.map(lambda d: d.week), 'Branch'])
```

... and look at the created subframes using:

```
def testgr(df):
    print df
gr.apply(testgr)
```

I get twice the first (following) group among the other groups which occur only once:

```
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity
0      A  Carl 2013-01-01 13:00:00         1
1      A  Mark 2013-01-01 13:05:00         3
```

Am I missing something here?

Thank you very much

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Apply iterates through every item in the dataframe.

A better way would be to print using the groups values:

```
In [31]: for v in g.groups.values(): print (df.iloc[v])
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
0      A  Carl 2013-01-01 13:00:00         1     1
1      A  Mark 2013-01-01 13:05:00         3     1
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
2      A  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00         5    40
3      A   Joe 2013-10-02 10:00:00         8    40
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
4      A   Joe 2013-12-02 12:00:00         9    49
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
5      B  Carl 2013-12-02 14:00:00         3    49
```

Compare to:

```
In [32]: g.apply(testgr)
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
0      A  Carl 2013-01-01 13:00:00         1     1
1      A  Mark 2013-01-01 13:05:00         3     1
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
0      A  Carl 2013-01-01 13:00:00         1     1  <- this dataframe is printed twice
1      A  Mark 2013-01-01 13:05:00         3     1
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
2      A  Carl 2013-10-01 20:00:00         5    40  <- this one isn't...
3      A   Joe 2013-10-02 10:00:00         8    40
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
4      A   Joe 2013-12-02 12:00:00         9    49
  Branch Buyer                Date  Quantity  week
5      B  Carl 2013-12-02 14:00:00         3    49
Out[32]:
Date  Branch
1     A         None
40    A         None
49    A         None
      B         None
dtype: object
```